# Boxplots with Pandas: nrows x ncols missing one plot

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I cannot figure out what is wrong here!
Basically, I am plotting 2x2 boxplots using the Pandas DataFrame method df.boxplot as follows:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(18, 16))
axes = axes.reshape(-1)
for i, crp in enumerate(["Cabbage", "Green beans", "Potato", "Wheat"]):
    print i, crp
    select = pd.Series(crp)
    df[df.Crop.isin(select)].boxplot(
        "Total_Irrigation_mm", by="Climate", ax=axes[i])
```

I iterate over the axes to plot for Cabbage, Green beans, Potato and Wheat. It does it fine for three crops then I receive the following error:

```
keys, values = zip(*gp_col)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack and the following output
```

[image]

My dataframe, df is:

```
     level_0  index       Crop       Climate               Year   Total_Irrigation_mm  
0          0      0       Cabbage       Humid continental  1981   248
1          1      1       Cabbage       Humid continental  1982   257 
2          2      2       Cabbage       Humid continental  1983   329
3          3      3       Green beans   Humid continental  1981   349
4          4      4       Green beans   Humid continental  1982   329
5          5      5       Green beans   Humid continental  1983   303
6          6      6       Potato        Humid continental  1981   278
7          7      7       Potato        Humid continental  1982   393
8          8      8       Potato        Humid continental  1983   393
9          9      9       Wheat         Humid continental  1981   393
10        10     10       Wheat         Humid continental  1982   393
11        11     11       Wheat         Humid continental  1983   393
12        12     12       Cabbage       Temperate          1981   393
13        13     13       Cabbage       Temperate          1982   393
14        14     14       Cabbage       Temperate          1983   393
15        15     15       Green beans   Temperate          1981   393
16        16     16       Green beans   Temperate          1982   393
17        17     17       Green beans   Temperate          1983   393
18        18     18       Potato        Temperate          1981   393
19        19     19       Potato        Temperate          1982   393
20        20     20       Potato        Temperate          1983   318
21        21     21       Wheat         Temperate          1981   312
22        22     22       Wheat         Temperate          1982   350
23        23     23       Wheat         Temperate          1983   152
24        24     24       Cabbage       Subtropical        1981   159  
25        25     25       Cabbage       Subtropical        1982   157 
26        26     26       Cabbage       Subtropical        1983   122
27        27     27       Green beans   Subtropical        1981   196
28        28     28       Green beans   Subtropical        1982   126   
29        29     29       Green beans   Subtropical        1983   188  
30        30     30       Potato        Subtropical        1981   123
31        31     31       Potato        Subtropical        1982   113 
32        32     32       Potato        Subtropical        1983   211
33        33     33       Wheat         Subtropical        1981   152  
34        34     34       Wheat         Subtropical        1982   158 
35        35     35       Wheat         Subtropical        1983   158



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1071-c19c414988ec>", line 7, in <module>
    "Total_Irrigation_mm", by="Climate", ax=axes[i])
  File "C:\Users\*\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4973, in boxplot
    **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\*\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 2368, in boxplot
    ax=ax, layout=layout, return_type=return_type)
  File "C:\Users\*\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 2763, in _grouped_plot_by_column
    keys, values = zip(*gp_col)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Comment: Please always add the full stacktrace, not only the error message. Besides, it is very difficult for us  to reproduce your issue without the data frame. Can you add a sample data frame for us which triggers the error?

Comment: FWIW your code seems to work for me with that dataframe.

Comment: @DSM so why is it not working for me?

Comment: @DSM Yup, it works! I had to clear the namespace.